# Is it possible to use ISR on-demand validation with multiple instances of NextJS?

Tags: next.js

I had a problem recently, there are 2 instances of NextJs in different servers, and there is an API for revalidating paths "/api/revalidate", but the problem is when using a load balancer with the servers, I can only reach and revalidate only one server, the other server would still use the old html. Is there a way around this? I'm using 'generateBuildId' to use the same buildID with shared storage, but it does not work with static html.

Comment: That should be possible, see https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration#self-hosting-isr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, turns out that the build is really cached inside the memoy. in-memory cache can be disabled using this in "next.config.js":

```
module.exports = {
experimental: {
  // Defaults to 50MB
   isrMemoryCacheSize: 0,
  },
}
```

Comment: wouldn't this make the server have no cache at all ?

Comment: The files are still cached as html, but not in memory.

Comment: This worked for me at a certain level. I'm using [Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/) with Scale-Out instances and when deployed directly, it works. But If I use [Custom Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-custom-container?tabs=dotnet&pivots=container-linux-vscode), it doesn't work I guess Azure can't know when content changed in one instance's container to sync up with the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution is to override the server, and implements a custom caching mechanism, for example, using redis to cache the html.

Comment: I don't know why this answer was downvoted, but this is now a feasible approach. In fact, this approach is recommended in the Next.js documentation now.